# Remove User From Yammer Group

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to programmatically remove a user(s) from a yammer group via the API?  Think of employee off boarding or department change scenarios and the system needs to remove the user from one group and add them to another.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Obtain the user's access_token using the impersonation endpoint, then send a DELETE request to: https://api.yammer.com/api/v1/group_memberships.json?group_id=

See this [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/israelo/2015/07/31/yammer-rest-api-how-to-bulk-add-members-to-a-yammer-group) for further details.